# Invisible Silverlight control

Tags: silverlight

I want to use Silverlight as a calculator-component (I want to run some computations client-side, and javascript is too slow for that)

I have a scriptable method on the SL, and everything works. Now, how do I make silverlight component invisible?

**EDIT:** Making component invisible won't work. Some browsers (Safari for one), doesn't work if component is invisible or is shown off-screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to set the Visibility attribute on the Silverlight element to Collapsed like so:

```
<TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

Or you can hide the entire object tag by using:

```
style="visibility:hidden;"
```

I'm not sure you'll gain much, since there will be overhead communicating to the Silverlight runtime plugin and the browser. Both run on the client (as you mentioned), but Javascript performs differently in different browsers. You would probably be better off optimizing your javascript.

Comment: The computation part runs for about 2 minutes in C#. It's an optimization NP-complete problem, even running an empty loop will take minutes on javascript.

Comment: `<object type="application/x-silverlight-2"...` is still visible. I guess I need to make the html-object invisible. How do I do that?

Comment: put style="visibility:hidden;" on the object tag

Comment: @Kevin, I accepted your answer in the comment, could you move your comment into the answer please, otherwise it appears as if I accepted the answer in the answer body (which I didn't)

Comment: making it invisible doesn't work. on some browsers (mostly on linx). Making it small (1x1) doesn't work either.

Comment: I just tried it on Chrome, IE 8, and Firefox and it works. The other browsers must implement it differently. You could try to match the background color of the object to the background of the page (style="background-color:white;").

Comment: in your comment you had "linx", I immediately thought of the text browser Lynx, but couldn't think of why you'd be using that :-). Linux has an implementation called Moonlight. maybe you could find some specific help here: http://www.go-mono.com/forums/.

Comment: correct. that's the silverlight implementation I am talking about. one that doesn't work on when SL component is disabled. :(